# Custom Date fFormat Validation

Tags: c#

I need to be able to validate user input from a text box. Can't use a date picker, wish I could but that's not an option. The only accepted format yyyyMMdd, do 20150113 for January 13, 2015.

Initially I thought this might work but it didn't:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var dateResult = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox_SearchPolicyEffectiveDate.Text,"YYYYMMDD",provider);
```

Then I tried

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 01, 13);
String.Format("{O:yyyyMMdd}", TextBox_EffectiveDate.Text.Trim());
```

This didn't work either but I'm puzzled by what goes inside the perents. Is that just an arbitrary data as really don't want to "hard code" my date in there. I was also looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) but it didn't offer much of what I can use. I saw other post where a format `yyyyddmm` is used so I thought I would just swap the 'mm' for 'dd' but that didn't work either.

Comment: use `yyyyMMdd` in your `ParseExact` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that you use the correct date format string in your second attempt, but not the same one for your `ParseExact` attempt. Anyway...

The format you want is `yyyyMMdd`. Note that case-sensitivity is really important here. `mm` is used for minutes.

If you want to validate then I would suggest using `TryParseExact`. Something like this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime? dt = null;
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox_SearchPolicyEffectiveDate.Text, "yyyyMMdd", provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Then you can check if it is valid and do whatever you want, for example:

```
if(isValid)
{
    // Valid so do something with the date value.
    model.MyDate = dt.Value;
}
else
{
    // Invalid so show an error message to the user.
    MessageBox.Show("Date format is invalid", "Invalid Date", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

You could also check for validity by doing:

```
if(dt.HasValue)...
```